# myWorksheet.Range.Resize.Value = array failing at high row numbers

Tags: .net, vb.net, interop, excel-interop

I've inherited a large project which uses Office.Interop.Excel to insert data into a spreadsheet.

In terms visible interaction, you click on a button and an Excel spreadsheet appears, with all the data already inserted. I mention this because I've seen it done elsewhere with the program already being open and values being inserted. The program I am working with inserts the data before Excel appears.

Unfortunately, once a relatively large amount of data is being inserted, the information transfer to Excel locks up and the program cannot continue.

Anyway, I did some investigating and found the following line:

```
myWorksheet.Range("A" & rowNumber).Resize(dataArray.GetUpperBound(0) + 1, columnCount).Value = dataArray
```

This copies all of the data in dataArray directly onto a bunch of cells in the worksheet.

I guessed that the problem might be caused by attempting to transfer such a large amount of data at once, so I altered it to copy data over row-by-row:

```
For horizIndex As Integer = 0 To dataArray.GetUpperBound(0)
    Dim subArr(0, arr.GetUpperBound(1)) As Object
    For columnIndex As Integer = 0 To dataArray.GetUpperBound(1)
        subArr(0, columnIndex) = dataArray(horizIndex, columnIndex)
    Next
    myWorksheet.Range("A" & (rowNumber + horizIndex)).Resize(horizIndex + 1, columnCount).Value = arr
Next
```

This will copy 350 or so rows to Excel and then the line setting Value simply stops returning.

Can anyone suggest a way around this?

EDIT: Okay, I've tried a bunch of what Lazarus suggested below, and here's where I am right now:

So long as the data is relatively short, or the datatypes are fairly simple (Integers, etc.) all variations of the code work fine. The original mass-copy works fine, the copy-by-line works and the copy-by-cell works, so long as the dataset is either small or simple.

My actual dataset, though, is relatively complex, and contains several datatypes, including Strings.

It falls over after 350-ish rows. It falls over on the Excel side of the code, the thread goes away to Excel and never comes back.

So, any more ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is with your ever expanding cell range.

I'd rework the line:

```
myWorksheet.Range("A" & (rowNumber + horizIndex)).Resize(horizIndex + 1, columnCount).Value = arr
```

to read

```
myWorksheet.Range("A" & (rowNumber + horizIndex)).Resize(1, columnCount).Value = subArr
```

### EDIT

Given that you are effectively iterating over every cell why not take advantage of that:

```
For horizIndex As Integer = 0 To dataArray.GetUpperBound(0)
    For columnIndex As Integer = 0 To dataArray.GetUpperBound(1)
        myWorksheet.Cells(horizIndex + 1, columnIndex + 1).Value = dataArray(horizIndex, columnIndex)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: @Lazarus I think you're probably correct. It now completes, but every single line is the same as the first. I'll go investigate that.

Comment: Oh, I'm a moron and I'm pasting dataArray into it every time instead of subArr. I see that you caught that before I did. Well done.

Comment: @Frost840: No worries, we've all sat with clumps of hair in our hands after hours chasing a bug that simply can't exist only to have a colleague amble over and point out the "elephant in the room" without effort :)

Comment: Okay, changing it to insert subArr makes it fall over at around 350 rows, again. :(

Comment: @Lazarus RE: Edit: I had thought about doing that, but I've always been a bit wary of doing array index lookups based on some hilariously awful performance I used to get from .net collections back before Generics were introduced. Trying it that way throws a really angry-looking COMException, which also appears to be complaining about late binding. I'm not sure whether that's progress from the program just sitting there doing nothing, or not o_O EDIT: Throws the COMException at the 350-rows mark

Comment: Maybe the answer is to format the data into a CSV format, save that to disc and launch Excel to load it. It's quick and dirty but until you can find a more appropriate solution...

Comment: GAH! Stupid StackOverflow comments! I never see the sixth. Yeah, I'm going to try that on Monday if nobody suggests anything miraculous over the weekend.